# Cursor Loaders filtering, old data shown in for a split second

Tags: android, listview, user-experience, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have a weird behavior in my App I'm struggling to understand.
I have 2 lists (A & B), the initial view is list A with a textBox on top that filters the results of list B.

I use cursor loaders, adapters and a listview to implement these 2 lists.

When the user enters a keyword to search, I restart Loader B with the entered keyword and load it into the adapter and set the listview to display adapter B.

Everything runs fine **BUT** instead of displaying the results right away, a wrong behavior happens: The full List B is shown for a split second, then the filtered results shows.
Of course this creates a very bad UX (user experience), what I want to achieve here is the filtered results to be shown right away without the split second view of the full list B.

I really want to understand why this behavior is occurring... after all this implementation style of querying is the one used in the official example of the cursor loaders :)

The code is too big but these are the most relevant parts:
This is the onTextChange that produces the bad behaviour:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{ 
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID_2, null, this);
}
```

These are the cursorLoader methods:

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
if (id== LOADER_ID_1)
    {
                //calculate and return cursorLoader
    }
  else
    {
           if (mFilter == null || mFilter.length() == 0) 
            {
                return new CursorLoader(this, uri, CAdapter.PROJECTION, null,null,null);
            }
//else
// do some calculations
return new CursorLoader(this,uri, CAdapter.PROJECTION, whereStmt, whereArgs, orderBy);
     }
}

public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
if (loader.getId()== LOADER_ID_2)
            {
                mCAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
            }
        else if (loader.getId()== LOADER_ID_1)
            {
             MatrixCursor newCursor = new MatrixCursor(DAdapter.PROJECTION);             
             if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                 do {
// basically I'm grouping filtering the returned cursor and populating the new matrix cursor with the filtered data because I didn't find a better way to filter and group results (get distinct rows)
             }while (cursor.moveToNext());
             }
        mDAdapter.changeCursor(newCursor);
//I used change cursor because the cursor loader will only handle closing the "cursor" and not the "newCursor" I created and put into the adapter, I hope this doesn't backfire :)
}

    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        if (loader.getId()== LOADER_ID_2 )
            mCAdapter.swapCursor(null);
        else if (loader.getId()== LOADER_ID_1 )
            mDAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) 
{
Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader
if (id== LOADER_ID_1)
{
//calculate and return cursorLoader
If(cursorLoader == null)
{
return new CursorLoader(this,uri,
```

CAdapter.PROJECTION, whereStmt, whereArgs, orderBy);
    }//end inner if

```
}// end if 
else if (mFilter == null || mFilter.length() == 0) 
{
return new CursorLoader(this, uri, CAdapter.PROJECTION, null,null,null);
```

}// end else if
}// end method

Comment: I'm not sure how this is relevant. Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: bytes? picture tag? .json in toast? I think you've mixed up my question with another :)

Comment: @kaBoz My apology, that comment is meant for another question.  I am deleting it now and did the answer I provided help thou?

Comment: I added a comment but somehow it's not here now. Anyway I was just telling you to check my previous comment when you posted your code:

 
I'm not sure how this is relevant. Can you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it. I was trying to check if any cursor is returned if the LOADER_ID = 1 else run fresh loader. I think because you returning null at the end might be why data shows then disappear if I am correct.